# Add a character to the beginning and end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a platform which uses a JavaScript-like syntax and allows to convert my values using regex.

I need to add a single quote at the beginning and at the end of a string, the string will always have 9 characters.

I.e.:

`123456789` should be converted to `'123456789'`

What expression should I use?

Comment: What does this have to do with regex? `"'" + num + "'"`

Comment: Whats the platform? And can you provide and example of what you might have to type?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression.

```
str = "123456789";

str = "'" + str + "'";
```

Comment: Thanks but this tool only provides you a "regex" option to convert the values so when I tried "'" + str + "'" it doesn't work. It expects me to use a regex syntax.

Comment: Apologies for wasting your time. This is working now. Your answer is not exactly what I did but the it reminded me that is was a simple solution :)

Answer (score 12):

Although this question was asked a little early, newly defined `backticks` standard called [*Template Literals*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-template-literals) from ES6 provides new possibility to solve this question with a simpler syntax:

```
const str = '123456789';
const wrapped = `'${str}'`;
```

Answer (score 7):

If its like Javascript you can do something like...

```
var myString = "'" + oldString + "'";
```

Where oldString is your 123456789

Answer (score 1):

```js
str = "123456789";
str = str.replace(/^/,"'").replace(/$/,"'")
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use literal `\` \'123456789\'.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just coerce to a String type:

```
var strValue = String(123456789);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively using lodash [`_.pad`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pad).

```js
var str = '123456789';
console.log(_.pad(str, 11, '\''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```